# Move privacy-policy-link to copyright

Tags: magento-2.1, xml

[image: Example]
How to move `privacy-policy-link` to `copyright`?

I have tried below code but this not work:

```
<move element="privacy-policy-link" destination="copyright"/>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`privacy-policy-link` does not showing because of **You have move privacy policy but the copyright.phtml does not have code to render child block**

**So, suggestion is that**

***edit your html/copyright.phtml and the  add then link beside the copy right section***

```
<?php
<small class="copyright">
    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getCopyright() ?></span>
<a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getUrl().'privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode' ?>"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Privacy and Cookie Policy') ?></a>
</small>
```